# what test should be put to get nested element

Tags: ios, nsxmlparserdelegate

Here is the case, title exist in two occurrences, before and after `entry`:

```
<feed xmlns:im="http://xxx.com/rss" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xml:lang="en">
    <id>http://xxxxx/xml</id><title>xxxxx: Top articles</title><updated>2013-07-20T04:30:05-07:00</updated><link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://xxxx;popId=1"/><link rel="self" href="http://xxxxxxx/xml"/><icon>http://xxxxxxxxxxx</icon><author><name>xxxxxxx</name><uri>http://www.xxxxx.com/xxxxx/</uri></author><rights>Copyright 2001</rights>

        <entry>
            <updated>2013-07-20T04:30:05-07:00</updated>

                <id im:id="621507457">https://xxxxx.xxxx.com/us/album/blurred-lines-feat.-t.i.-pharrell/id621507456?i=621507457&amp;uo=2</id>
                 //I want to get only the title nested in entry tree
                <title>Robin Thicke</title>
```

What test should be made in `didStartElement:` protocol method in order to escape any  outside the `<entry></entry>`?

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
      //This is not enough, since it bring also the title value which is outside the entry tree
    }
}
```

I don't want to rely on an external library like TBXML, I want to know wether this is doable in pure `NSXMLParserDelegate`?

Comment: I am not going to answer your question, but give you a list of "better" xml parsers: http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-choose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

Comment: I already read that article, I need a way to do so with pure NSXMLParserDelegate without relying to another library. Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep track of whether the parser is currently "inside" an `entry` element or not.
For example, you can
add an integer property `entryLevel` to the class,
set it initially to zero
 and update it in `didStartElement`
and `didEndElement`:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"entry"]) {
        self.entryLevel++;
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"] && self.entryLevel > 0) {
        // title inside entry
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"entry"]) {
        self.entryLevel--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I will accept this solution as long a it appears to me there is no other way to test nested levels.